# Change effective id

Tags: permissions, uid

I'd like to know how to change my effective uid

mike628@NASBD122F:/etc$ id -G
1000 0 121

I belong to these groups, but I cant do anything as root, when things are owned by root:root

and can someone explain this clearly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Belonging to group `root` isn't equal to being `root` user because User ID (UID) and Group ID (GID) are different things and for most (all?) privileged activities you need to have effective UID == 0 and having GID == 0 is not enough for that.

To switch your effective user your need to use `su` or `sudo` commands.

Comment: I figured it out on my own ....edit the passwd file

Comment: @mike628: Editing the password file to do what you want is not a good idea.  Any programs run using your id will have full access to the system overriding entirely the intent of using unprivileged accounts.

Comment: Hi Bill, My point was never to overide, but to understand what was/is going on under the hood.Now I can change it back to the correct setting. What I got out of it was that this can be done and how